# How to apply a function throughout an iterable?

Tags: python, data-structures, iterator

I want function `f` that working style is:

```
>>> f(chr, [65, 97])
['A', 'a']
>>> f(chr, {65, 97})
{'A', 'a'}
>>> f(chr, {65: 'upper_a', 97: 'lower_a'})
{'A': 'upper_a', 'a': 'lower_a'}
```

`map` is lazy, so I have to do`list(map(function, iterable_ds))`, but this way spoiling the **original** data structure.

How can you do this?

---

One day when trying to write `f`, I geting this questions?

Every data structure class with `__iter__` is iterable but like `__next__()` give next element in any iterable then what special function will give upower add any xyz to iterable d.s.? Why append is for list only and add is for set? Why no common interface like `__iter__` and `__next__`?

---

I tried

```
def f(func, i_ds):
    ctor = type(i_ds)
    holder = list()
    for _ in i_ds:
        new_val = func(_)
        # now what add? append? update? xyz? I hope ctor can consume list
        holder.append(new_val)
    return ctor(holder) # I know I know it fail for dict type easily
```

I can write f to handle dict but

- it is ugly
- what if tomorrow I get 2 Tree d.s. written by different people

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PaulRooney: I think they just mean it means ending up with a `list` unconditionally rather than whatever the input was. They may not understand that the `list` part of `list(map(...))` can be changed to any other compatible constructor that takes an iterable of input values to initialize the collection.

Comment: @PaulRooney I mean final output is list even if inputs dict, set, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Mappings (`dict`-like things) are fundamentally different from other collections, so you won't be able to avoid special casing them entirely, but you can at least limit the amount of specialized code required. While you're right that there is no common "add item to collection" API, most collections accept an iterable of values to the constructor.

Using that constructor based ducktyping, a minor improvement on what you've got would be:

```
import collections.abc

def f(func, it):
    res = map(func, it)
    if isinstance(it, collections.abc.Mapping):
        # Pair up mapped keys with original values
        res = zip(res, it.values())
    return type(it)(res)
```

This doesn't require any intermediate temporary data structures (`map` and `zip` are lazy generator based functions; they produce values only when constructing the return type at the end). It assumes that all non-`Mapping` types can be constructed from an iterable of values, while all `Mapping` types can be constructed from an iterable of pairs; for general purpose built-in collections (`tuple`, `list`, `set`, `frozenset`, `dict`), this is the case. Less general containers won't necessarily work (`bytes` would depend on the result of `func`, `str` wouldn't work without special casing to use `''.join`).

That said, what you're trying to do is unnecessary. Your `f` function is replicating `map`, badly. Since it's never possible to write a function such as yours with perfect type replication, it's better to do as `map`does and leave it to the caller to repackage the results in whatever data structure is appropriate (e.g. for `dict`s, they can explicitly pass mapping functions that expect a key/value `tuple` and pass `.items()`, then construct the `dict` from the result; really they probably want a `dict` comprehension).

After all, what you're asking for is never going to work for *every* input type, simply because constructors don't always follow the same rules. For example, this code won't work with `collections.defaultdict` because that takes the `default_factory` as the first argument, with an iterable initializer coming second (violating our expectation that the first argument is the iterable initializer). Trying to handle that means more special cases, and you're just making it harder and harder to determine what `f` actually does. Is it really so hard for the callers to explicitly do: `{myfunc(k): v for k, v in mydict.items()}` rather than `f(myfunc, mydict)`, or `[myfunc(x) for x in mylist]`/`list(map(myfunc, mylist))` over `f(myfunc, mylist)`?

Comment: Thanks. I thought some variant of `map` could perform function *in-place* - modify as it traverses d.s. but I get your

Comment: @vvsLaxman: In-place modification definitely couldn't be done; if your `func` is `lambda ch: chr(ord(ch)+1)`, and you pass it a `dict` of `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`, if it processes `'a'` first, you'd end up replacing `'b'` (it's illegal to modify the set of `dict` keys during iteration in any event, even if there was no overlap). Same problem applies to `set`. Only `list` could do something faintly reasonable (using `enumerate` and assigning back to each index as it goes, or even more simply, `mylist[:] = map(func, mylist)`).

Answer (score 1):

I think that [`functools.singledispatch()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/singledispatch.singledispatch) may provide you required functionality keeping the code clear.

```
from functools import singledispatch


@singledispatch
def f(i_ds: list, func):
    holder = list()
    for val in i_ds:
        new_val = func(val)
        holder.append(new_val)
    return holder


@f.register(set)
def _(i_ds: set, func):
    holder = set()
    for val in i_ds:
        new_val = func(val)
        holder.add(new_val)
    return holder


@f.register(dict)
def _(i_ds: dict, func):
    holder = dict()
    for k, v in i_ds.items():
        new_key = func(k)
        holder[new_key] = v
    return holder


print(f([65, 97], chr))
print(f({65, 97}, chr))
print(f({65: 'upper_a', 97: 'lower_a'}, chr))
```

singledispatch works for first argument only, but you could use multipledispatch third party library (https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch)

When new data structure type arrives, you will need to register new function for it.

Comment: This is a clever idea; I've never really bothered to use that decorator but this is a good use case for it. It's really just special casing each data type (internally, it does a lookup in a `dict` of supported types and calls the function associated with it), but at least the code for each special case isn't mingled together into a single massive ugly function.

Comment: Wow awesome how did this idea strike you?

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I really love your answer ;)